# Continuous-time Wiener Process probability question

Tags: probability

for a continuous-time Wiener process with $var [X(t)] = t$, what is the probability $P[|X(t)| > 1]$ ?

I have been reading about the Wiener process aka, Brownian motion. My understanding is that the expected value of Brownian motion at any point will always be 0 and is normally distributed. The variance, t increases proportionally with time - so at time, $t = 1$, variance = 1.

I am not sure how to characterize X(t) as a probability, however. If we wish to find the probability of the function when it is greater than 1, wouldn't this be all values for which time, $t > 1$? Can anyone help my understanding? Would this mean as t $\rightarrow\infty$ , probability of $X(t)$ is 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X(t)$ is, by definition, normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $t$. Thus $P[|X(t)| > 1]=P[|X(t)|/\sqrt{t} > 1/\sqrt{t}] = 1-(N(1/\sqrt{t})-N(-1/\sqrt{t}))$ where $N$ is the normal CDF.

You seem to be getting confused with properties of a sample path $X(t,\omega)$ for $t \in [0,\infty)$ with the random variable $X(t)$ for a fixed $t$.

Remember, $X$ is a stochastic process, meaning for all $t$, $X(t)$ is a random variable. There is nothing inherently related about $X(t)$ and $X(s)$ when $t \neq s$ for an arbitrary process. However, a Weiner process is special, having continuous paths, and having independent normally distributed increments.

Comment: Do you think you could explain how you came to your first equation? I've been trying to come to the same solution but haven't had success using what is provided in my text. Is asking what happens as t tends to infinity the same as asking X(t) > 1?

Comment: The first equation is simply dividing both sides by $\sqrt{t}$. Since $X(t)$ is $N(0,t)$ distributed, $X(t)/\sqrt{t}$ is $N(0,1)$ distributed. If you want to take the limit as $t \to \infty$ just do so. From the right side of the equation we see the limit is $1 -( 0 - 0) = 1$. I.e. $P[|X(t)|>1] \to 1$ as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: thanks for the quick and clear explanation! I understand now :)